# Analog of Glib quarks on Mac OS

Tags: cocoa, hash, macos, glib, core-foundation

Maybe you know any analogs of g_quark_from_string() and g_quark_to_string() in CoreFoundation or other frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare prototypes of those functions and link your application against libglib-2.0.a . You may use glib-2.0 from macports (/opt/local/lib/libglib-2.0.a).